# (How) Should the wife of the ba'al habayit (homeowner) be mentioned in the call to recite grace after meals

Tags: bentching, zimun

As part of leading birkat hamazon (grace after meals) there is a custom for the leader to mention he has been given permission to lead by the male homeowner.

I am wondering if there is any discussion about whether or not to include, and if so how, the spouse (female co-owner) in this dialogue.

Ie: b'rshut baal habayit u'baalat habayit

Sample zimun texts for reference
[RCA Artscroll Siddur](http://www.kakatuv.com/pdfs/bbb-orthodoxO/002shabbat-at-homeO/002birkat-hamazonO.pdf)
[Tefillos.com](https://www.tefillos.com/birkas_hamazon.asp)

Comment: Why, she can't do zimmun anyway, its the husbands right to give the honour

Comment: https://www.etzion.org.il/en/shiur-58-zimun-6-mezamen

Comment: I'm unaware that there is any protocol regarding whom you wish to honor or mention. Most siddurim I've seen don't even mention *ba'al habyit*. But, I have heard what you mentioned as well as the phrase *ba'al habayit ve'ishto*. I've heard people mention even "habanim vehabanot* in situations where the entire family pitch in for some part of the meal. (It's nice to acknowledge the 5-year old girl who helped mommy mix the batter and shape the cookies, or the 7-year old boy who helped mommy get some things at the supermarket!)

Comment: Can you source that custom? Anyone can mention anyone they want (real, imaginary, living, dead, male, female, human, alien or dog) before Zimmun so the only way this is on topic is if you can source the existence of some Jewish standard to try to meet

Comment: @user why does whether she can lead the zimmun affect who has the right to give the honor? You just made that up!

Comment: Thought experiment: the husband asks you to lead and the wife asks you not to (or vice versa). What would you do? I'd probably stay awkwardly silent.

Comment: @DoubleAA I am unaware of a source which states that you have to ask/mention that the homeowner (or anyone else) has given you reshut to lead the bentching. I added links to examples of zimun texts to show this is commonly done.

Comment: If all you want to know is what is commonly done then just go outside and check. Not sure that is alone on topic without some Judaism based reason for doing this.

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/103506/170

Comment: @Double AA no he didn't make it up.  making zimun due to an obligation. However the Baal habayia has din kedimah. If a kohen is present permission is 'asked' from him as well as they have a din kedimah for honour as well.

Comment: @oranges you're talking about a different case, where no one has the right to decide and some decision needs to be made (like friends in a pizza store). Then by default it goes to eg. a Kohein. To see it another way, the right to determine who leads is the person in charge of the meal and they may have a Mitzva to choose the Kohein or Mitzva to choose a guest. It's not the Kohein's right until they do so though, because they are in charge. In a home with a mom and three sons, you can bet your bottom dollar she's in charge of what happens in her home with her sons at her meal.

Comment: Worth noting that we do of course wish blessings upon both the man and woman of the house in the horachamons (at least ashenazik custom)

Comment: @Oranges really? I've heard many Ashkenazi people say יהי רצון שלא יבוש בעל הבית הזה and rarely do I hear שלא יבושו בעלי הבית הזה. Maybe just your experience is different from mine, but it's hardly a universal Ashkenazi practice

Comment: @Double AA I'm referring to the 'hora Harmon hi yivorech es Baal habayia hazeh, ves baalas ' etc.

Comment: @user15464 not entirely correct, see Brachot 45b

Comment: @AlaychemRememberMonica when wommen are on their own they might be able to lead a zimmun for each other (halacha is not like this opinion), but with men they have absolutely no option to lead, according to every opinion as a mans obligation is Min Hatorah and a womans is a safeik

Comment: @user15464 That's not true. Only when there is a minyan can women not lead. Without a minyan the women may split and lead their own. That's the halacha (though it practically rarely happens).

Answer (score -1):

i've innovated: *birshus ba'al habayis u'bizchus ba'alas habayis*.
i hope that is satisfactory to all without implying that the woman is asked to defer her priority to lead the benching...
and it is the zchus of the female head of the household that enables the meal + the benching. acknowledgment of her integral contribution is imho also warranted for the sake of shalom bayis.

Comment: Very similarly -- I'm told one of the popular "YU feeder" yeshivas in Israel -- KBY, I think? -- does *birshus ba'al habayis ubichvod baalas habayis*. A gracious nod to the hostess (without whom you wouldn't be there!) without going full-on egalitarian.

Answer (score -1):

The Kol Bo (21) brings the custom to request permission before *zimmun*:

> ומדרך המוסר לכל מי שיברך שיטול רשות מן הגדולים המסובים שם

This custom to say ['ברשות' before *zimmun*](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9B%D7%A3_%D7%94%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A2%D7%9C_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A7%D7%A6%D7%91#%D7%A1%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%A3_%D7%90) is found when someone who has the first rights to *zimmun* is present, like a *baal habayis*, father or a *kohein*.

Because women are not obligated in *zimmun*, there would seemingly be no reason to request their permission.

R' Yitzchok Zilberstein (*Chashukei Chemed, Berachos* pg 276) writes regarding three sons sitting by their mother, that the *mevarech* should say *birshus imi morasi*. Although a woman is not obligated in zimmun and therefore has no precedence, there is still a different reason to request permission from the mother. This is because the Rambam writes:

> ולא ישב לפני רבו עד שיאמר לו שב, ולא יעמוד מלפניו עד שיאמר עמוד, או עד
> שיטול רשות לעמוד

Because the laws of *kibbud em* are similiar to *kibbud rabo* (see Pischei Teshuva YD 240:6), this would apply equally to one sitting with his mother. Therefore, there is reason to request permission even though she is not obligated in *zimmun*.

Comment: Actually, a woman eating with her three sons IS obligated in zimmun.

Comment: "This custom to say 'ברשות' before zimmun is found when someone who has the first rights to zimmun is present, like a baal habayis, father or a kohein." I don't see any source for this in your link (or anywhere in Judaism). You are building a straw man to then tear it down. Indeed the only reason ever to ask permission is proper manners as you conclude. This is not a chiddush.

Comment: Woman are obligated in zimun same as men, they just don't join with men to make a zimun.

Answer (score -3):

I heard a lecture on "the feminist movement in Judaism" that mentioned some examples that have direct נ"מ to your question:

1. We follow the rule of אשתו כגופו, like it is customary to address a couple as "Mr. and Mrs. Eli Berkowitz", so my wife is included with me. When we bless בעל הבית we refer to him, his spouse and his whole family.
2. As even Avizarayu deArayos are Deorayso (as with Rambam - לא תקרבו לגלות ערוה) the sages minimized possible interactions with married women. You know, first comes blessing, then winking and then we have 50% rate of divorces. So it might be considered immodest (in some communities).

Anyway, the part you're referring to is optional (either the beginning or the end of Birkas Hamozoyn) so everything that goes there is purely traditional (a Minhag).

Comment: I would never address a couple as "Mr and Mrs Eli Berkowitz" (unless he was Eliezer and she was Eliana, and even then I'd probably opt for Elis Berkowitz). Does Judaism really care how you formulate English honorifics?

Comment: @DoubleAA When we're invited to a wedding of our American part of the family in Israel, the table notes say exactly that, I didn't make it up, I was surprised myself. Yes Judaism cares, when we send invitations we say רבי אליהו ומשפ' where משפ' refers to the spouse.

Comment: That's odd. The invitees to my wedding didn't get cards like that. (And no, Judaism doesn't care at all. Your community may have some peculiar arbitrary custom, but that has nothing to do with Judaism.)

Comment: "First comes blessing and then comes winking." Tell that to the malachim who asked Sarah how Avraham was doing ...

Comment: @Shalom Malachim are not subjected to Halacha #2

Comment: We are not afraid to mention women during the bless. Just google the phrase "הרחמן הוא יברך את בעלת הבית הזה"