# Is it permissible to say “Birshut Baalat HaBayit Hazeh” when saying the Rabotai Nevarech invitation?

Tags: bentching, zimun

Some people have a custom of adding “Birshut Baal Habayit hazeh” in the Zimun. Can the wife be included?

Comment: Do you have any reason to think it might be prohibited? No worse than saying Birshut R2D2 or skipping the line entirely

Comment: Incidentally what if the Baalat HaBayit isn't a wife?

Comment: Didn't someone just ask this

Comment: No reason to think it’s prohibited. In my family we’ve always said it when appropriate. Someone at a table said it was assur and I’m interested in hearing people’s thoughts.

Comment: And yes, the baalat habayit doesn’t have to be a “wife”. Nor does the baal habayit have to be a “husband”.

Comment: @Ben It's hard to find sources permitting something there is no reason to prohibit

Comment: @robev someone asked should a wife be mentioned. this asks can she. Both are kind of silly since the whole practice under discussion is entirely optional and subject to absolutely zero halakhic regulation.

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/103305/how-should-the-wife-of-the-baal-habayit-homeowner-be-mentioned-in-the-call

Answer (score 8, accepted):

R' [Shlomo Aviner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shlomo_Aviner) was asked this question, and his response-- published [on his website](http://shlomo-aviner.net/index.php?title=%22%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%91%D7%A2%D7%9C%D7%AA_%D7%94%D7%91%D7%99%D7%AA%22_%D7%91%D7%96%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%9F_(%D7%9E%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%A8))-- was that this **WOULD** be permissible for two reasons:

#### 1) The wording isn't an essential part of benching

> הנוסח הזה הוא **לא מעיקר הזימון**
>
> That wording **is not the essence of the *zimun***.

The "birshus" is merely an addition. Sephardim, Ashkenazim, Yemenites, Yiddish-speaking people-- each of these people have their own versions for this portion.

#### 2) מעיקר הדין, Women DO have an obligation of *zimun*

> מעיקר הדין, נשים חייבות לזמן לעצמן כשיש שלוש נשים ופחות משלושה אנשים. וכשאנשים מזמנים, נשים עונות. אמנם נשים נהגו לא לזמן לעצמן משום צניעות (ע' שו"ע או"ח קצט, ו-ז. מ"ב שם. ערוך השולחן שם ס"ב. שו"ת תשובות והנהגות ד נא), אבל צניעות אינה מבטלת את עיקר הדין.
>
> **א"כ, לא נהגו להוסיף "ברשות אמי" או "ברשות בעלת הבית", אבל מותר, וכ"ש שבודאי אין למחות על אחרים שאומרים.**
>
> Women are obligated to summon themselves when there are three women and fewer than three people. And when men lead *zimmun*, women answer. It is true that women do not normally lead *benching* out of modesty (Shulchan Aruch, OC 199: 6-7, ibid. etc), but modesty does not nullify the essence of the halachah.
>
> **Therefore, while it was not customary to add "in the authority of my mother" or "in the possession of the landlady", it is permitted to do so, and all the moreso one should not protest against others who say it.**

Comment: #2 is an esp. interesting take. This would directly explain the concept of "asking permission" of the Mrs. I've heard one person include all the children as well. Basically, it was a way of thanking everyone who was involved in preparing the meal, including the tots who helped mom bake or pick out the groceries. Why not acknowledge everyone? They deserve it.

Answer (score 0):

We had this topic discussed on a Shiur from R' Ben Tzur (IIRC) in our Kollel a couple of years ago. He said:

1. Because Zimun is a "stand-alone mitzvah", in addition to the obligation of Birkas Hamozoyn, it is a Zchus to perform it.
2. Because only one person can do that, it goes automatically to the host or to the most knowledgeable Rabbi (or a Cohen) **according to rules of precedence**. If someone else is Mezamen, he has to ask for an explicit Reshus (permission) from that person to have the merit of this Mitzvah.
3. Technically, if the Mezamen person is lower in precedence that several other people, all of them must be asked in that order.
4. Simce the host's wife does not have the right to be Mezamen, she is not/can not be asked for permission, just as the people lower than him (like his own kids) can not be asked.
5. However, eventually, people forgot the original reason for asking permission and imagined that it is a matter of appreciation (as @Danf said "*Basically, it was a way of thanking everyone who was involved in preparing the meal*") and started to add whatever they imagined. While it is not a Halachic problem on its own, it shows a lack of understanding of the reason for asking that permission in the first place.

Comment: This post skips an important step which belies its lack of understanding of the practice: what if, as in the vast majority of cases, there is a tie?

Comment: @DoubleAA The reason for Reshus is the precedence of Zchus, not appreciation. Theoretically a humble person can ask Reshus from all people he *considers* smarter (or higher on this scale) than him, but a woman can't bentch, she's not on the list in any way.

Comment: of course it's not appreciation. In a woman's house she has the right to determine who leads even if she didn't eat. Similarly in a man's house if he didn't eat with the guests. The whole idea of a list is a joke in that context and the whole idea that you have to be a part of the zimmun to have rights to determine what happens under your roof is even more ridiculous. This is just made up nonsense to protest what some think is a dangerous feminist breach of Minhag. Save your fight for something that matters, I say

Comment: @DoubleAA Maybe in America. Here in Israel we follow the Halachah. Women decide what's cooking, but not what's been said and by whom.

Comment: So you are agreeing that all you said is nonsense and it just so happens that in your community it's not expected ettiquete that she'd be in charge of things outside her kitchen. In such communities indeed thered be no point in asking her permission. נהרא נהרא ופשטיה it just depends on the local customs.

Comment: Whether or not Al Berko agrees that his answer is nonsense, I believe that it is not (the comment about the cooking was unfortunate). In fact, while the wife has the right to determine which customs are followed in her own home, she does not have the right to decide who leads zimun. In the same way that she may not prevent zimun taking place (other than by preventing three men from being invited in the first place). Even in someone else's home, the Torah comes before the instructions of the homeowner.

Comment: @tcdw that is not true. Halakha mandates respecting the Baal habayit. You may not speak aloud without their permission. If they don't let you pray, they may be violating halakha by being mean, but you then have to leave. You can't just ignore them. It's their property and their domain. See Shulchan Aruch הנכנס לבית כל מה שיאמר לו בעל הבית יעשה

Comment: @DoubleAA The respect required for the Baal habayit does not override the obligation to bentsch with zimun in the place that you ate - you will not find anything to the contrary in Shulchan Aruch or in any reputable halachic source.

Comment: @tcdw I just showed you something in a reputable halachic source. But anyway this is just a red herring since the question is who gets to pick when the baal habayit does allow the zimmun. Whether or not someone can ban you from saying zimmun is not what indicates who gets to pick the leader. Even were you right that the homeowner can't prevent the zimmun, they still get to pick who leads. If they anyway try and prevent it and fail, they've simply waived their right to pick and we revert back to the case of friends in a pizza shop with no homeowner

Comment: @DoubleAA The source you refer to cannot mean that one must listen to everything the homeowner says, including murder, idolatry etc. and I don't think you believe this either. Regarding picking who leads, unless stated explicitly otherwise, I would think it is fair to assume that when two people own the home, the permission of the one who is involved in the zimun is sufficient. Even if there is only a ba'alat habayit, under normal circumstances it would be strange for her to care (although in this case I agree that it would be respectful to ask permission).

Comment: @tcdw then we agree it just depends what's normally accepted for her to care about in her house. Against this answer that there is some objective reason she can't have an opinion.

Comment: @DoubleAA I would say that there is an objective reason that it would be silly for her to have an opinion (like it would be silly for men to have an opinion about seating arrangements in an Ezrat Nashim). I would question whether this is at all normal in any community, except for those where women do join zimun with men.

Comment: @tcdw ok well then we're just using words differently from each other. Enjoy your formulation. (And unless I misunderstood you, in all Halakhic communities women join the men's zimmun, and are in fact obligated to do so.)

Answer (score 0):

i've innovated: birshus ba'al habayis u'bizchus ba'alas habayis. i hope that is satisfactory to all without implying that the woman is asked to defer her priority to lead the benching... and it is the zchus of the female head of the household that enables the meal + the benching. acknowledgment of her integral contribution is imho also warranted for the sake of shalom bayis.

Comment: A) iv heard this before. B) this might be unfortunately a disparagement to the zimun as an extraneous interruption

Comment: @Naftali only in the sense that I "might" be an animate watermelon. there can't be an interruption in something that isn't halakhicaly meaningful

Comment: @DoubleAA According to a prominent rabbi [who I dont name :) ] the introduction is part of zimun and "lchvod baalat habayit" is a disrespectful digression. Also, according to Ben Ish Hai the Reshut section of Zimun actually has mystical significance.

Comment: @Naftali goes to show how little prominence is worth these days :) it can't be a part of zimmun if no one said it till the last couple centuries and it factually still isn't required. anyone can make up what they think is respectful or not, but let's not misrepresent halakhic categories to disguise our personal pet peeves

Comment: I personally view the Torah informed sensitivities of Talmidei Chachamim as Daat Torah and not pet peeves. Also, according to Ben Ish Hai it is mandatory

Comment: No @Naftali according to the Ben Ish Chai it's a kabbalistically meaningful bonus. It is never halakhicaly mandatory. And Daat Torah is no excuse to perjure halakha. You can say Daat Torah informs you that such a line, or any line, is disrespectful on its own. But you can't say it's an interruption or that the interruption makes it disrespectful. I can also imagine lines that are disrespectful ("birshut the poopy in the diaper") but Im not calling them interruptions or assigning any technical halakhic significance to them. It's just my opinion of whats bad taste and disrespectful in context